# How to define services and access it in controller?

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a service file containing following lines of code.

```
namespace App\Service;

/**
 * Class MyService
 * @package App\Service
 */
class MyService
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $newTest;
    /**
     * MyService constructor.
     * @param string $newTest
     */
    public function __construct(string $newTest)
    {
        $this->newTest = $newTest;
    }
}
```

I have defined it under `service` section in `services.yaml` file.

```
my_service:
    class: App\Service\MyService
    bind:
        $pcValue: '%env(resolve:LATEST)%'
```

Now I am trying to retrieve this `pcValue` at the controller,

```
$this->get('my_service');
```

It is returning me following error:

```
`Service "my_service" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\WheelController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using dependency injection correctly to take advantage of auto-wiring.

In order to have your service available on your controller you just need to add the type-hinted service in the desired action in your controller.

Check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/autowiring.html)